# How can I find out which Ray version is installed on kuberay?

Tags: ray, kind, kuberay

Running on [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/), I've installed kuberay following the [docs](https://ray-project.github.io/kuberay/components/operator/).

I brought up the dashboard:

> k port-forward svc/raycluster-heterogeneous-head-svc 8265

But this doesn't show any version information

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the `ray --version` command inside the head pod, the following did the job for me:

> kubectl exec `kubectl get po |awk '{print $1}' |grep head` -- ray --version

Which returned the following for me:

> ray, version 2.2.0